# Node.js child process hanging, need debugging ideas

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process, spawn

This question might be kinda weird because I'm not quite sure how to ask it. I'm looking for help isolating a bug in some Node.js code I'm working with that spawns some child processes that run some jobs in parallel. The bug is essentially that the last process spawned by the code hangs indefinitely when the code is run.

To clarify what I mean by "hangs indefinitely", I mean that the process never exits, or at least never appears to do so at the terminal.

The method implemented for this was taken from a SO answer to begin with, though I can't find it to link it at the moment. I've coded a dummy version without the implementation specifics:

```
    const { spawn } = require('child_process');
    const tasks = ['task.js', 'task.js', 'task.js', 'task.js', 'task.js', 'task.js', 'task.js'];

    function doThings(tasks, pool){
      let numRunning = 0;
      let tasksRun = 0;

      function doMoreThings(){
        while (tasksRun < tasks.length && numRunning < pool){
          const runnerCmd = `node`
          const params = [`${tasks[tasksRun]}`]
          console.log(`Starting task ${tasksRun + 1} out of ${tasks.length}`)
          const child = spawn(runnerCmd, params, {
            stdio: 'inherit',
            detached: true
           })
          ++numRunning;
          ++tasksRun;

          child.on('exit', code=>{
           --numRunning;
           doMoreThings();
          }).on('error', err=>{
           console.log(`${err}`);
           doMoreThings();
          })
        }
      }
      doMoreThings();
    }

    doThings(tasks, 3);
```

```
And here is the task.js file:
```

```
    console.log('Task starting...');
    const max = 5000;
    const min = 1000;

    const sleep = (waitTimeInMs) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, waitTimeInMs));

    const timeval = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);

    console.log(`Task interval: ${timeval}ms`);

    sleep(timeval).then(() => {
      console.log(`Task completing after ${timeval}ms`);
    });
```

The above dummy code all works as expected. The processes run, their output is printed to the terminal, and when the last process exits, the terminal returns to a command prompt from the running state.

So, finally, what I'm hoping for are ideas from anyone more experienced with Node child processes or parallel job execution in general on how a bug could be introduced to the above code that would cause the last job in the chain to never exit. Or maybe the bug is already there in some race condition I'm not perceiving that just doesn't manifest with such a simple test? Been trying to debug this for a while and I don't have any more ideas about what to try. Thanks in advance to anyone who even attempts to help.

Comment: Why do you call doMoreThings recursively? You already loop over all task in the first call of it, don't you?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to check this. That function is called recursively because the while loop exits when the number of tasks running reaches the maximum allowed (the `pool` parameter, i.e. process pool). Calling the function again from the exit event of the child processes is how we either run more tasks if more are left or finish up altogether.